# Making Powershell retry upload to Pushover if it failed

Tags: powershell, upload

I want to upload a notification to Pushover's servers through Powershell v2.0.

I got this (which works fine):

```
param ($token, $message, $title, $url, $url_title, $priority, $html, $timestamp)
$parameters = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
$parameters.Add("token", "$token")
$parameters.Add("user", "$user")
$parameters.Add("message", "$message")
$parameters.Add("title", "$title")
$parameters.Add("url", "$url")
$parameters.Add("url_title", "$url_title")
$parameters.Add("priority", "$priority")
$parameters.Add("html", "$html")
$parameters.Add("timestamp", "$timestamp")
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.UploadValues("https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json", $parameters)
```

When for whatever reason I get **a response other than an HTTP 200 (OK) status** (see https://pushover.net/api#response) **or NO response** I want to make Powershell retry the Upload. How can I do that? I don't even have a clue how I could get the response alone.

Can somebody please give me a working piece of code?

Comment: how many times do you want to retry sending a request?

Comment: maybe 5 times... spaced 10 seconds each?

Answer (score 1):

Capture the response like this:

`[byte]$responseArray = $client.UploadValues(uriString,myNameValueCollection);`

Read the byte array response like this:

`$response = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($responseArray)`

You can then write your code the address the HTTP response values with the results.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.
In fact I won't be needing PowerShell knowledge ever again. I'd be very grateful if you gave me a working piece of code that I simply had to copy and paste to the end of my code. Is that possible? *big eyes*